# Android firebase apply multiple queries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following database

```
-KYTfJZQbg0RVzHeecIS
     createdAt: 1481204648530
     message: "rgd"
     read: false
     reciever: "583d15cf45f3330807364c55"
     sender: "58490e9945f33364ac6cd7b1"
     updateAt: 1481204648654
```

Now I want to filter the result for "READ"==FALSE AND "SENDER"==58490e9945f33364ac6cd7b1

how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

EDIT :-

I am using this in android as

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("read").equalTo(false)
                .orderByChild("sender").equalTo(datum.getEmployer().getEmployerId());
```

it gave `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!`

Answer (score 6):

Multiple orderbychild() queries is not supported by firebase .

> Now I want to filter the result for "READ"==FALSE AND
>   "SENDER"==58490e9945f33364ac6cd7b1

Make a new key in your data i.e. READ_SENDER and combine data for both and use query like this -

```
-KYTfJZQbg0RVzHeecIS
     createdAt: 1481204648530
     message: "rgd"
     read: false
     reciever: "583d15cf45f3330807364c55"
     sender: "58490e9945f33364ac6cd7b1"
     read_sender : "false_58490e9945f33364ac6cd7b1"
     updateAt: 1481204648654


Query query = reference.orderByChild("read_sender").equalTo("false_"+datum.getEmployer().getEmployerId());
```

Comment: or just add method `public String getReadSender(){return read+"_"+sender;}` to Item.class. But the method should be WITHOUT annotation `@Exclude`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this isn't straightforward using Firebase.....there's good example of doing something very similar in following video by Firebase guys (about 9 mins in) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=4

Comment: We can not use multiple orderby like this Query query = reference.orderByChild("read").equalTo(false)
                .orderByChild("sender").equalTo(datum.getEmployer().getEmployerId());   else it will throw exception :-   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!

Comment: yes, that's exactly what's discussed in the section of that video I mentioned above.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly how to achive result?

Comment: Not working because in this video show same think:-

Query query = reference.orderByChild("read").equalTo(false)
                .orderByChild("sender").equalTo(datum.getEmployer().getEmployerId());