# Multiple query on firebase

Tags: php, android, mysql, performance, firebase

i am trying to filter loaded database according to different filters inserted by users, these filters may be activated or not
in order to do these filtration using firebase i came across some limits that's been discussed here [Android firebase apply multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041385/android-firebase-apply-multiple-queries)

i have around **5 filters** that exists on my application
so in order to use the same technique in the answer i would need to do something like that

[image]

and by assuming the name can be ideally searched too.

for the answers posted here [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

i can't also use the **create a custom index programmatically** solution as my filter do have some dynamic values such as names and some filters may/may not exist

is there any other solution for that?

what is the available approaches using database server to host the database and php script to communicate with it?

- i have no experience in web development

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this using Firebase and PHP. Maybe you can take a look in the follow link: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html

Comment: i will use server to access the firebase as normal by using admin access, then the request will write to firebase and mysql !?